# What is a minimal set of rules that determine the usual order on $\Bbb{N}$ given that $1 \lt p_1 \lt p_2 \lt \dots$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, order-theory, natural-numbers

Let $p_i$ always mean the $i$th prime number.

Given two numbers $a, b \in \Bbb{N}$ in the form $a = \{(p_i, e_i) : p_i^{e_i} \mid a, e_i \text{ maximal}\}$ ie. essentially their unique factorization, what is a natural way to compute whether $a \gt b$?

For instance a rule might be $p_{j}^2 \gt p_{j+1}$ always.  So that given $a = 2^2$, $b = 3$, we immediately have  $a \gt b$.

Is there a simple set of rules such that given the usual ordering on the primes and $1$: $1 \lt p_1 \lt p_2 \lt \dots$ we can always derive $a \gt b$ when it is true?

By no means can we include converting the number to a base representation and comparing the last digit.

It's best to work by example sometimes.  Take $2 \cdot 7 \lt 3\cdot 5$.  Well, $2 \lt 3 \lt 5 \lt 7$ so... ?

I'm stuck on this one, what is the simplest rule you can think of to overcome this example?

Comment: It's certainly true that, given only the information $p_1<p_2<p_3<p_4$, there's no way to determine which of $p_1p_4$ and $p_2p_3$ is larger.

Comment: Or how about comparing $2^{11}3^25^97$ with $p_{10\ 000\ 000\ 000}?$  I don't expect there to be a simple rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some evidence that this may be hard.

In mathematical logic class we learn that the theory of $(\mathbb N,\times)$ is decidable. Basically, because the fundamental theorem of arithmetic states that the monoid of positive integers under multiplication $\times$ is a [free commutative monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid#The_free_commutative_monoid) on an infinite set of generators, the prime numbers.

But if we add in the relation $x< y$, you get the same definable sets as in all of first-order arithmetic $(\mathbb N,+,\times)$, which is not decidable. This is described by [Alexis Bès](http://lacl.univ-paris12.fr/bes/publi/survey.ps).